# Turbolinks not working - instead loads page twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

So, in my Rails 4 app I have Turbolinks gem.

```
//= require jquery.js 
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
```

However, something seems to be wrong. Isn't the point of Turbolinks that you don't have to load all the jquery/css/asset pipeline other than once at start? Well, that doesn't seem to happen, and it proceeds to load all jquery each time new page is requested, and what's more, it even makes each page load **twice**. Such as:

```
Started GET "/" for ip at 2014-01-21 18:55:35 +0200
*Loads bunch of stuff here*

Started GET "/" for ip at 2014-01-21 18:55:35 +0200
*Loads bunch of stuff here*

Started GET "/assets/jquery.js"
Started GET "/assetsjquery_ujs" 
Started GET "/assets/litecarousel"
Et cetera...
```

When I comment out `//= require turbolinks` the console seems to show only one page load, which is normal. What could be the cause of this?

I have many jquery functions with $(document).ready, but with *jquery.turbolinks* this should be just fine.

**// EDIT:** Tested out a few things and it seems it's a bug related to Chrome. Works good on Firefox. Also, my version of the gem is v.2.2.0.

Comment: Encountered the same problem. Had to disable turbolinks for specific pages so that it wouldn't load twice break some of my logic, but would be nice to find the cause!

Comment: Yeah, a little testing on my own and it seems to be a Chrome problem in the first place. Works good on Firefox. However, there was a solution that required Turbolinks to be updated to v. 1.3.1. However, I have (as probably you also) v.2.2.0 and the problem still persists. Hopefully someone has more info on this. Will update here what I find out.

Answer (score 2):

Have you put the line `<%= javascript_include_tag ... %>` between the `<body>` tags of your page instead of in the `<head>`? I was getting all kinds of weird errors from Turbolinks once and this was the cause.

Comment: With turbolinks the scrips must go in `<head>`. The reason for this is that Turbolinks works by swapping out the `<body>` when changing pages, and doing so will re-execute all your third-party scripts (imagine jQuery being re-evaluated), which may not be what you want. https://coderwall.com/p/ypzfdw/faster-page-loads-with-turbolinks

Comment: That's my point - I'm telling him to make sure his scripts are in the head, not body.