# How to Get Bootstrap Navbar to Expand with Turbolinks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

In my Rails 4 app, I'm using Bootstrap's Navbar.  When the Navbar is collapsed, it doesn't always expand/toggle when it's clicked on.  The menu icon shows, but when you click on it, it doesn't do anything:

[image: The menu icon shows, but when you click on it, it doesn't do anything.]

I know that it's related to `Turbolinks` because it never happens when I enter the url of a view manually, only after I click links.  Also, it goes away when I remove `Turbolinks` from the app completely.

Based on these questions:

- [Bootstrap dropdown stops working after I switch pages - Rails 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018447/bootstrap-dropdown-stops-working-after-i-switch-pages-rails-4-2)
- [Bootstrap 3 dropdown doesn't work with Rails 4 & Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132384/bootstrap-3-dropdown-doesnt-work-with-rails-4-turbolinks)
- [Turbolinks not working - instead loads page twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264809/turbolinks-not-working-instead-loads-page-twice)
- [Bootstrap navbar collapse button unclickable in rails 4, bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325822/bootstrap-navbar-collapse-button-unclickable-in-rails-4-bootstrap-3)

I've tried these things, but none fixed the issue:

1. Moving stylesheets and javascripts to the Body
2. Setting `data-turbolinks-track='false' for all javascripts and stylesheets
3. Setting `'data-turbolinks-eval' => false` for all javascripts and stylesheets
4. Using `jquery-turbolinks`

Interesting to me, is that other Bootstrap elements, like the menu dropdown don't have this issue with `Turbolinks` for me.

I know I can remove `Turbolinks`, but I'd rather keep it if possible.  Is there a way to do this?

My view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-danger navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation-demo" id="demo-navbar"  data-no-turbolink ="false">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2" data-no-turbolink ="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <%= image_tag " logo.png"%>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-example-2" data-no-turbolink ="false">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Games", games_path %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Days", days_path %>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-->
</nav>
```

gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.1.0'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: This is specially very weird!, because if other elements on the page work it seems that the issue may not be turbolinks, and you set up seems to be right, could you tell us what does the javaScript console shows when you click the navbar?

Comment: problem is not what is shown here, i have just copied your code and pasted in my rail 4 app with turbolink but it just works fine without any issue menu is working , try to see as mentioned by @SsouLlesS

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming upon this in 2023 or later with Rails 7, Bootstrap 5, and turbo-rails gem (because Yes it's STILL an issue and I've spent days trying to fix it because none of the old Rails 4/5 + jquery solutions apply since Bootstrap 5 doesn't use jquery anymore) I finally found a way to solve the problem:

Add `data-turbo="false"` to your outermost navbar HTML element in the view layout .html.erb file. This seems to keep the navbar from falling victim to the "not really reloading" issue but keeps performance high with turbo everywhere else.

Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top mt-0 pt-0" data-turbo="false">
```

From the turbo official docs:
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms